# PayU api to make payment via card

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, payumoney, payu

I am using payU (payment gateway) to make payments . I have explore the Api to create new order but after successful call of this Api it took me to new page where user should enter card details.
I want to make custom design but couldn't find any api to send card details of user and capture payment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think that PayU is limited to their form. The only integration that I know in that way is with Stripe.